# How to convert unknown characters to UTF-8 with php?

Tags: php, curl, encoding, character-encoding, json

I'm sending a request to a web page via curl in php and getting this as response:

```
���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~�G�Y��?z��ݧ�y�.�q֬��ٛ�U��W��Y�-�M��K�z��a,
```

Normally the response should be like this:

```
{"value":"/Default.aspx?aType=UyeIlanListe"}
```

Already tried to json_encode, mb_convert_encoding ($return, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1") and mb_convert_encoding ($return, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8") functions.

What am i missing here ?

Here is the original screenshot of response:

[image]

[image: response and post headers]

[image: posted data]

[image: response]

[image: json]

Comment: have you tried character encoding in your php script?

Comment: @HarshalMahajan how should i try this can you be more clear ?

Comment: Your issue is not the encoding: no standard encoding would produce such a result on that input, and if you're dealing with some ultra-weird custom encoding, that should be defined somewhere relating to that webpage. This looks more like compressed or encrpyted data, assuming it isn't just corrupt.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen added firebug information. Things are how it should be in firebug but encoding has a problem in php.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen turns out you were right... it's compressed data. Gzip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution was adding gzip encode option to curl:

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is gzip.

After using gzip decode function problem solved:

```
function gzdecode($data) 
{ 
   return gzinflate(substr($data,10,-8)); 
}
```

p.s. a built-in gzip decode function will be available in PHP 6 according to manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php